# Actual value for CSS property like "auto", "inherit", etc in inspector?

Tags: css, web-inspector

Is there a way to find out the actual value the browser uses when the CSS value is set to "auto" or similar? I'm looking at the computed CSS values for an element in the inspector but it stills says "auto" and I would like to determine the exact value.

**UPDATE**: Looks like *most* properties automatically compute, but some don't. Here are examples of properties that *still* show up as "auto" when you look in the computed panel:

- top
- bottom
- left
- right

Not sure why.

<sup>If anyone was wondering, the reason I was even trying to figure this out is because I'm currently maintaining a website using an older version of Bootstrap (v2.1.1), which sets top for .modal.fade.in to "auto" when in a browser with a width < 768px. Which, for my browser at least, results in the modal vanishing from view. So naturally I wondered where the modal had gotten to and wished I could see the actual value Chrome set top to.</sup>

<sup>Looks like one of the changes in (v2.2.x) was changing top: auto to top: 20px which would probably fix the issue.</sup>

Comment: *"I'm looking at the computed CSS values for an element in the inspector..."* I think you're looking at the *applied* values, not the *computed* ones.

Comment: Have you looked at the *Computed* tab next to the *Styles* tab?

Answer (score 5):

In chrome you have tab `computed`. You see those values there.

[image]

**Computed** tab

[image]

http://jsbin.com/yefofe/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of the computed tab. Turns out it's not calculated for certain properties.